# Solution to the equation $\;-\sin x=\:0\;\;$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

What is the solution to the following? $$-\sin x = 0\;$$

I've tried it and I concluded $x=\pi$ but my friend said it should be $x=2\pi.$

What is the correct answer?

Answer (score 8):

Both of you are partially correct:

$$-\sin x = 0 \iff \sin x = 0 \iff x = k\pi, \;k \in \mathbb Z$$ So yes, $\pi$ is a solution, as is $2\pi$, and $0$, and $-\pi$, etc. Any integer multiple of $\pi$ is a solution.

Comment: Ohh, can you explain why/how?

Comment: Have a look to the circle and loop around it ! Cheers :-)

Comment: $\sin x$ is periodic, with period $2\pi$. In particular, if you look at the graph of $\sin x$, you'll see that it intersects the x-axis $(\sin x = 0)$ at every integer multiple of $\pi$. Alternatively, both $0$ and $\pi$ are solutions, so $2\pi $ must be (one full rotation about the unit circle from 0), and $3\pi$ must be a solution (as it is one full rotation about the unit circle from $\pi$.

Comment: If your task is to find the solutions to $-\sin x = 0$ in the interval $[0, 2\pi]$, then $x = 0$, $x= \pi,$ and $x = 2\pi$ are the three solutions for $x \in [0, 2\pi]$.

Comment: Thank you! Very informative. How about in the interval [-2pi, 2pi], would it be x = pi, 2pi, 0, -pi ?

Comment: Almost. All the values you list, **and** $- 2\pi$. Five solutions on $[-2\pi, 2\pi]$.

Answer (score 1):

Have look at this

http://www.humblesoftware.com/demos/trig_d3

nice animation. In the circle you see the triangle where the considered angle increases and you see how the length of the "opposite catheti" side of the triangle - which is the sine of the angle (if the length of the hypotenuse / radius is one)- varies. 
It gets projected to the right as well and forms the sine curve pattern. 
You should understand at what angles the sine vanishes.